# Is there anything special about Christmas Day?

Tags: fallout-4

I fast traveled to Diamond City today and was greeted with this:

[image: Christmas in Diamond City]

[image: Takahashi's Christmas Tree]

Checking the in-game date, it is indeed the 25th of December, or Christmas Day.

Is there anything special about this day specifically, other than the cheerful cosmetic overhaul of Diamond City? Are there any quests or special items which are only available on this day?

Comment: I also can't confirm this, but I could've sworn I heard a Diamond City Guard say *"Ho Ho fuckin' ho"* in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking since I saw this question asked yesterday and haven't been able to find a single quest or special event on any of the holidays. So its safe to say that the holidays are 100% cosmetic. If and I repeat IF there are any quests or anything special happening on the holidays its hidden pretty well because no one has said anything about finding a special quest on those days. I even looked for unique holiday related random encounters and didn't find any so ether they don't exist or just unlucky.